# $route.reload(); is not working

Tags: angularjs

I have two pages included on single page which has new-registration form and listing user form below that. At a time I am showing that two things.

What I want is, once I enter the new entry in database, my listing page should be reloaded. I have used `$route.reload` for that. On submit button, I am calling one function to save the data in database, and after submitting I am calling `$route.reload`.

But What is happen like sometimes it is working and sometimes it doesn't.

I am using AngularJS 1.3.

I have tried `$window.location.reload();` but it didn't work for me.

Somewhere in blog, I have seen like that reload function is not supported for angular 1.3 or less version, then why is it working sometimes.

Can anyone suggest other things to reload the things at a time only once the new record get insert and  can some one suggest like where I am getting wrong while using `route.reload`?

Comment: AngularJS is an SPA (single page application) that should never refresh the page (only render new content). Have you considered clearing/resetting the data instead of refreshing?

Comment: hi, Thank you for the reply.
Actully From google only, I have got this solution "$route.reload".
On submit button, I am calling one function in that I am calling webservice to save the data. and after savong the data, or after the completion of webservice, I am calling $route.reload function in that

Comment: use this  window.location.href = window.location.href; inside $route.reload(); I think it should work.

Comment: I am rendering the content only, but that all contents is available in different html page. Thats why I am calling page refresh

Comment: check my answer may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly,

```
window.location.reload()
```

reloads the current page with POST data, while `window.location.href=window.location.href` does not include the POST data.

`window.location.href=window.location.href` will not reload the page if there's an anchor (#) in the URL - You must use `window.location.reload()` in this case.

Also, as noted by @Mic below, `window.location.reload()` takes an additional argument skip Cache so that with using `window.location.reload(true)` the browser will skip the cache and reload the page from the server. `window.location.reload(false`) will do the opposite, and load the page from cache if possible.

Comment: Thanx @Man, for the reply, but when I used it , my page was continuously getting refreshed and sometimes I was getting blank page.

Comment: I don't have your code, but it looks like you are running this inside a loop, you have to break it after one successful execution.

Comment: make it window.location.reload(false) after successful execution. So it will stop getting into loop

Answer (score 0):

$route.reload function is available for angular version 1.3 see docs https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Are you using two different controllers for that two views?

Comment: Yes, I am using two different controller. Like for Adding data, I have written one controller and for viewing data, different controller is there but in same module.

Comment: The $route.reload should work if the module is included properly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually why you want to reload the page? If you want to reload every time (while inserting,updating,deleting)?

See,

- You can just push  the `$http` response object (newly added) to existing array.
- or Just call the `defaultLoad()` function after insert success callback